# How to set HttpResponse Header for Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, model-view-controller, controller, httpresponse

I have to write a unit test for a function that Imports and Converts a Cvs file to Components
To make that work I initialised the Controllers HtpContext in the Test. as follows

```
public async Task Parse_ValidCsv()
{
    //*
    Test Data is implemented here 
    *// 
   var controller = _provider.GetService<ComponentController>();
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            var streamContent = new StreamContent(new                           

    MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_fileContent)));
            content.Add(streamContent, "file", "file.csv");


    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext();
    controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContentType =   
    content.Headers.ContentType.ToString();
    controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Body = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var response = await controller.Parse() as JsonResult;
    _jobs = response?.Value as Dictionary<string, Guid>;
    var dictionary = _jobs;
    Guid id;
    _jobs.TryGetValue("job", out id);
    var resultSetNew = await controller.GetImportJobResults(id, 1, 0, 5,"","").ToListAsync();
...

}
```

That works so far and in the Debug Mode i can see that the Components are correctly parsed.
The error i encounterd now happens in following function

```
 private IQueryable<T> QueryResults<T>(IQueryable<T> query, int? skip, int? take, string orderBy,  
 string filter, bool supportWildcards = false, bool updateHeaders = false)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter)) query = query.Where(supportWildcards ?   
         filter.TreatQueryNonWordCharactersAsWildcard() : filter);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orderBy)) query = query.OrderBy(orderBy);

    var count = query.Count();
    var range = (take.HasValue, skip.HasValue) switch
    {
        (true, true) => $"{Math.Min(skip.Value, count - 1)}-{Math.Min(skip.Value + take.Value - 1,     
        count - 1)}",
        (true, false) => $"0-{Math.Min(take.Value - 1, count - 1)}",
        (false, true) => $"{Math.Min(skip.Value, count - 1)}-{count - 1}",
        (false, false) => "*"
     };

     if (updateHeaders) Response.Headers.ContentRange = $"entries {range}/{count}";
     if (skip.HasValue) query = query.Skip(skip.Value);
     if (take.HasValue) query = query.Take(take.Value);
            
     return query;
}
```

In the Line if (updateHeaders) Response.Headers.ContentRange = $"entries {range}/{count}";
A Null Exception is thrown. How do i initialize the Response.Headers correctly?

I tried setting the headers in the Arrange Part but because it is readonly i cannot do it.